# Integrate spam checking before sending an email in python django

Tags: python, django, email, spamassassin

I'd like to implement a way to check an outgoing email in django if it has a high spam score by way of clicking a button to read the email contents. This way, I could modify the email to be less than the spamassassin score of 5 or 10 (something like aweber's implementation) prior to sending it to my contacts.

Any help or pointers is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find anything?